# Convert number in textbox to month name for vba statements

Tags: vba

I have a textbox wherein I input number as months (like "01" for January) but I need the actual month name instead of the number in my VBA statements. Can you please help me convert the number in the textbox into Actual Month Name.

I have tried the statement below but it is not working:

```
 Dim MoName As String
MoName = Format(Month(Monthtxtbx.Text), "MMMM")
Range("Cells(1,1):Cells(LastCol, Lastcolumn)").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=MoName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MoName = MonthName(Monthtxtbx.Text)` to get the month name.

---

Alternatively, you could dummy up a date so that you could use the "mmmm" format as:

```
MoName = Format(DateSerial(2000,Monthtxtbx.Text,1), "MMMM")
```

but that would be the long way to achieve something simple.